# Python program not returning anything

Tags: python

I'm practicing Python so I decided to recreate the max() function for 2 numbers. The code doesn't have an error, it just doesn't return anything. Please help! `

```
def newMax(num1, num2):
    if num1 > num2:
        return num1
    elif num2 > num1:
        return num2
    elif num1 == num2:
        return "They're both equal!"
    else:
        return "We've run into some sort of error. Make sure you entered 2 numbers."
print("This program will return the largest of 2 numbers you enter.")
number1 = input("Please enter your first number.")
number2 = input("Please enter your second number.")
newMax(number1, number2)
```

`

Can you not call a function with variables as the parameters, and if not then how would I write this program? FIGURED OUT, I had a print statement error, sorry.

Comment: print(newMax(number1, number2))

Comment: It returns alright. It doesn't print anything, though.

Comment: You don't do anything with the return value of `newMax`. Perhaps take a look at a beginner's guide to Python?

Comment: How\where do you run this code? Is this code entered to IDLE or saved in a file?

Comment: Remember to cast user input into a number, i.e. `float` or `int`.

Comment: Runtime error  ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new_max = newMax(number1, number2)
print(new_max)
```

Try assigning it to a variable and printing that variable.